# How to print a latex section title from the R code using knitr?

Tags: r, printing, latex, knitr, cat

I am trying to produce a simulation report in Latex with knitR. My R code has a loop on products and generate a graph for each products. I want to include a section title for each loop iteration. I used resuls='asis' and tried to print the section title in the loop as in the code chunk below:

```
<<looptest, echo=FALSE, results='asis', warning=FALSE>>=
for (product in c("prod 1","prod 2")){
    print(paste("\\section{",product,"}", sep=""))
}
@
```

The issue is that I get this in the latex output:

```
[1] "\\section{prod 1}"
[1] "\\section{prod 2}"
```

Comment: The solution is to use cat() instead of print() . 

    <<looptest, echo=FALSE, results='asis', warning=FALSE>>=
    for (product in c("prod 1","prod 2")){
        cat(paste("\\section{",product,"}", sep=""))
    }
    @

Has the correct latex output:

    \section{prod 1} \section{prod 2}

Comment: That's a little much for a comment. Post it as an answer and accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thomas suggested me to post this as an answer. 
The solution is to use cat() instead of print()

```
<<looptest, echo=FALSE, results='asis', warning=FALSE>>= 
for (product in c("prod 1","prod 2")){ 
cat(paste("\\section{",product,"}", sep="")) }
@
```

Has the correct latex output:

```
\section{prod 1} 
\section{prod 2}
```

Comment: Mine gives a ! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \sect when I do     #cat(paste("\\section{",field,"}", sep="")). Any thoughts?

Comment: @and0rsk - that's because R sees \\s as "\s", which is an undefined control sequence. Try 

    cat(paste("\\\\section{", field, "}", sep = ""))

Answer (score 2):

If you are looping through something to generate sections/chapters dynamically, I suggest use the loop functionality by `knit_child`. See [the code from knitr-examples](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/020-for-loop.Rnw) on GitHub.

Comment: Or similarly, the `knit_expand` examples: https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/075-knit-expand.Rnw, https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/075-template.rnw

Comment: If the real use case is as simple as the OP described, I think `cat()`  suffices; otherwise, either `knit_child()` or `knit_expand()` can be better ways to go.